# Is there a way to save Cucumber Reports from Jenkins in your local or shared directory?

Tags: jenkins, automation, cucumber

Im currently working in Jenkins and I noticed that the Cucumber Reports in Jenkins are saved on the # link of the jobs. Is there a way or plugin for Jenkins to create a new folder per job run and save them in my local?

Comment: I will start with some questions. What kind of reports are those? Are you using extent report or you are using Jenkins plugin to publish the report in Jenkins? There is no way in Jenkins to create a folder and store the reports that are generated by Jenkins plugin in your system unless you are authorised to create the Jenkins  nodes. If the reports are getting generated during the execution then there are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: I am new to Jenkins and used Cucumber Reports plugin to generate it.

Comment: Oh in that case I need some time to create a utility for that. May be tomorrow I will be able to share that. I hope that is okay for you :)

Comment: Meanwhile you can look into the below utility. May be this can help you 

https://github.com/frostyaxe/CucuReporter

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thank you so much!!